# Configuring Raid for 36 disks Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have 36 disks that I want to configure for Raid. The first 2 I have setup for Raid 1 in linux basic template but for the others i have 8x 1.7 SSD's and 26x 8 SATA's.

the 8 + 26 = 34 drives are all JBOD raid config. Is this the right way to configure or do I have to have an individual {} for each drive?

```
"storageGroups": [
            {
                "arraySize": 8000,
                "arrayTypeId": 2,  # Raid 1
                "hardDrives": [
                    0,
                    1,
                ],
                "partitionTemplateId": 1  # Linux Basic
            },
            {
                "arrayTypeId": 9, # JBOD
                "hardDrives": [
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    6,
                    7,
                    8,
                    9,
                    10,
                    11,
                    12,
                    13,
                    14,
                    15,
                    16,
                    17,
                    18,
                    19,
                    20,
                    21,
                    22,
                    23,
                    24,
                    25,
                    26,
                    27,
                    28,
                    29,
                    30,
                    31,
                    32,
                    33,
                    34,
                    35
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I also tried:

```
    "arrayTypeId": 9, # JBOD
    "hardDrives": [21]
},
{
    "arrayTypeId": 9, # JBOD
    "hardDrives": [22]
},
```

etc...

but keep getting timed out in the verifyOrder()

Comment: you need to post all the order, only some packages of bare metal servers support such amount of disk we need to review that the package you are using is the correct, also you need to make sure that this is not an issue in your side due network connections

Comment: Hi Nelson, It's too long to post but i'm using Dallas 10, package 555 which from the portal, says 36 drives.

Comment: the issue is your side

Answer (score 0):

the storage group configuration is fine the issue must be in your side, review that your network connection does not have timeouts.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> **JBOD** drive must have exactly 1 drive

So you need to define this for each disk, that's the issue, you should try something like this:

```
 "storageGroups":[  
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":2,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        0,
                        1
                    ],
                    "partitionTemplateId":1
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        2
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        3
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        4
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        5
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        6
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        7
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        8
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        9
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        10
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        11
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        12
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        13
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        14
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        15
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        16
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        17
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        18
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        19
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        20
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        21
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        22
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        23
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        24
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        25
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        26
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        27
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        28
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        29
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        30
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        31
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        32
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        33
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        34
                    ]
                },
                {  
                    "arraySize":8000,
                    "arrayTypeId":9,
                    "hardDrives":[  
                        35
                    ]
                }
            ]
```